# Use the numbers $1$ to $4$ to add up to $4$

Tags: puzzle

It is stated: "**A pathway measuring four units in length can be paved in exactly eight different ways using any combination of paving stones measuring one to four units in length.**"

My attempt: The combinations I could find were: 
$$1,1,1,1$$
$$2,1,1$$
$$1,2,1$$
$$1,1,2$$
$$3,1$$
$$1,3$$
$$4$$

However, these are only 4 combinations. **What combination am I missing?**

Comment: There's also $2$,$2$

Comment: What about ones like $2,2,2,2$ and $1,2,2,3$?

Comment: "These are only 4 combinations" when you just wrote down 7 combinations???

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have missed 
$$
4 = 2 + 2
$$